# Python: get index of each item in list with duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I get the index of each item in a list, including duplicates? As far as I know python list.index will only give me the first index of a duplicated item, like this.

```
registros = ["Celda", "Celda", "Test", "Celda", "Celda", "Celda"]
    for item in registros:
        index_found = registros.index(item)
        print(str(index_found) + " " + dato)
```

Outputs:

```
0 Celda
0 Celda
2 Test
0 Celda
0 Celda
0 Celda
```

So how do I do (as simple as possible) to get this desired output?:

```
0 Celda
1 Celda
2 Test
3 Celda
4 Celda
5 Celda
```

Comment: `enumerate`...?

Comment: never used enumerate, could you ellaborate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/522578/4909087

Comment: Thanks :D I'll check that.